# Javascript is not firing on page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

My javascript is working after the page loads but it's not hiding the detailed1 and detailed2 div on initial load. I'm setting the value on my codebehind when calling the view but the javascript is only firing when the user changes the current value after the page has loaded.

Here's my code at this point:

```
@using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes
@using MobileServiceForms.miscclasses
@using MobileServiceForms.Models
@model HomeModels.AsmeForms

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tank Inspection";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.UserType').change(function () {
      var value = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
      if (value === "Detailed") {
        $("#detailed1").show();
        $("#detailed2").show();
      }
      else if (value === "Summary") {
        $("#detailed1").hide();
        $("#detailed2").hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Please fill out the form below and click SUBMIT when you are done.</p>

<hr/>

<div>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAsmeForm", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SummaryOrDetailedEnum, "Detailed", new { @id = "Class_UTCompany", @class = "UserType" }) Detailed
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SummaryOrDetailedEnum, "Summary", new { @id = "Class_UTCompany", @class = "UserType" }) Summary
    </div>

    <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Account Number</label>
    <label class="baselabel labelbottom">@Model.BranchNumber-@Model.AccountNumber</label>

    <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Tank Serial Number</label>
    <label class="baselabel labelbottom">@Model.TankSerialNumber</label>

    <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Date of Inspection</label>
    <label class="baselabel labelbottom">@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</label>

    <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Tank Size</label>
    <label class="baselabel labelbottom">@Model.TankSize</label>

    <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Inspector's Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
    
<div id="detailed1">

  <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Inspection Type</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InspectionType,
    new SelectList(Model.InspectionTypeList),
    "Select an option",
    new { @class = "form-control comboboxnoblock" })

  <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Relief Valve Date</label>

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReliefValveMonth,
    new SelectList(Model.ReliefValveDateMonthList),
    "Select an option",
    new { @class = "form-control comboboxnoblock" })

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReliefValveYear,
    new SelectList(Model.ReliefValveDateYearList),
    "Select an option",
    new { @class = "form-control comboboxnoblock" })

  <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Relief Valve Manufacturer</label>

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RelieveValveManufacturer,
    new SelectList(Model.ReliefValveManufacturerList),
    "Select an option",
    new { @class = "form-control comboboxnoblock" })


  <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Relief Valve Set Pressure 250 psi</label>

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReliefValveSetPressure,
    new SelectList(Model.ReliefValveSetPressureList),
    "Select an option",
    new { @class = "form-control comboboxnoblock" })

  <label class="baselabel labeltop lesserfont">Relief Valve Capacity</label>

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReliefValveCapacity,
    new SelectList(Model.ReliefValveCapacityList),
    "Select an option",
    new { @class = "form-control comboboxnoblock" })

</div>

    <div class="spacer">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.WeepHoles, new { @class = "checkbox" })
      <label class="lesserfont">The weep holes are open and free of discharge.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Corrosion, new { @class = "checkbox" })
      <label class="lesserfont">There are no signs of corrosion, cracks, debris, tampering, or other mechanical damage.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Leakage, new { @class = "checkbox" })
      <label class="lesserfont">There is no leakage.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Discharge, new { @class = "checkbox" })
      <label class="lesserfont">The pressure relief device discharge meets the requirements of Clause 12.2.2 of CSA B51. (there is no obstruction to the path of discharge)</label>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Seal, new { @class = "checkbox" })
      <label class="lesserfont">The Seal (where applicable) has not been broken.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RainCap, new { @class = "checkbox" })
      <label class="lesserfont">The Rain Cap, (where applicable) has been installed.</label>
    </div>

    <div id="detailed2">
      <div class="spacer">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Manufacturer, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        <label class="lesserfont">The manufacturer's data plate or markings are present in accordance with the applicable design code (UL, CSA, CGA, NB).</label>
      </div>

      <div class="spacer">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Pressure, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        <label class="lesserfont">The Set pressure of the pressure relief device meets the specified.</label>
      </div>

      <div class="spacer">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DischargeCapacity, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        <label class="lesserfont">The discharge capacity of the pressure relief device is equal to or greater than the boiler output capacity stamped on the boiler name plate and complies with clause 12.2.1.2</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input class="allformsbutton" type="submit" value="Submit" id="buttonAsmeDetailed" />
  }
</div>
```

In the code behind I am setting the value of SummaryOrDetailedEnum and it's setting the right value in the RadioButtonFor on the form but it's not hiding the detailed1 and detailed2 divs accordingly.

If SummaryOrDetailedEnum equals "detailed" then I am showing those div ids. If it equals "summary", I'm hiding those ids.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Shouldn't the js execute when the value changes on the initial load?

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Code-behind is executed on the server; your browser / JS code has no idea that you're using ASP.net, much less does codebehind trigger a client-side `onchange` event. Code-behind runs -> result is sent to browser -> HTML / <script>s are parsed -> scripts are executed in order -> potentially, user input triggers `change` event

Answer (score 0):

your code is doing exactly what you are telling him to do, you are instructing that only make the divs visible when someone changes the checkbox, so, instead, keep the divs hidden and only make them visible on the change function.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#detailed1").hide();
    $("#detailed2").hide();
$('.UserType').change(function () {
  var value = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
  if (value === "Detailed") {
    $("#detailed1").show();
    $("#detailed2").show();
  }
  else if (value === "Summary") {
    $("#detailed1").hide();
    $("#detailed2").hide();
  }
 
})});
```